# Json.NET output only value in C#

Tags: c#, json.net

How can I get only values when I use a **JsonConvert.SerializeObject**? I don't need repeat words like id, name, etc...

Example:**{ id: 189, name:'Paul', age:31, } x { [189, 'Paul', 31] }**

Thanks!

I need to use with PageList class

```
public class PageList {
    IEnumerable _rows;
    int _total;
    int _page;
    int _records;
    object _userData;

    public PageList(IEnumerable rows, int page, int total, int records, object userData) {
        _rows = rows;
        _page = page;
        _total = total;
        _records = records;
        _userData = userData;
    }

    public PageList(IEnumerable rows, int page, int total, int records)
        : this(rows, page, total, records, null) {

    }

    public int total { get { return _total; } }

    public int page { get { return _page; } }

    public int records { get { return _records; } }

    public IEnumerable rows { get { return _rows; } }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public object userData { get { return _userData; } }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" });
    }
}
```

Comment: How will you refer to the properties when you send that second thing on? You might as well stick to arrays then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of is

```
var yourObjectList = List<YourObject>(){.....}

string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetObjectArray(yourObjectList));

public static IEnumerable<object> GetObjectArray<T>(IEnumerable<T> obj)
{
    return obj.Select(o => o.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.GetValue(o, null)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I try to use with Pagelist class but I get error when try to use IEnumerable in GetObjectArray(yourObjectList), do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The second one is not valid JSON ( `{ 189, 'Paul', 31 }` ). Maybe you want an array instead (`[ 189, 'Paul', 31 ]`), in which case you can instead of using the serializer directly, first load the object into a `JObject`, then take only its values.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public int age;
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo { id = 189, name = "Paul", age = 31 };
        JObject jo = JObject.FromObject(foo);
        JArray ja = new JArray();
        foreach (var value in jo.Values())
        {
            ja.Add(value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(ja);
    }
}
```

Or if you really want the non-JSON format, you can also use the `JObject` enumeration and print the values yourself.

Comment: Thanks, can you help me to use with PageLList class?